Trying to host a Flutter project trough Firebase but when using Flutterfire it returns a Formatexception how do I solve this?
As the title says I am trying to host a Flutter app. But when I followed the guide in my Firebase console to add a Flutter app I keep getting stuck. My operating system is Windows and the Firebase guide to add a Flutter app is as follows:
Prepare your workspace:

Install the Firebase CLI and log in (run firebase login)

Install the Flutter SDK

Create a Flutter project (run flutter create)


I had already a Flutter app with the latest release of the Flutter SDK. Some poblems came with installing firebase. I wanted to do it with npm but that didn't seem to work so I decided to use the standalone binary and place this one in my Flutter app folder (I also renamed the standalone binary to firebase.exe). After that it seemed to work and I was able to run Firebase and run Firebase commands in my wokspace powershell.
Install and run the FlutterFire CLI
Now it is time to install the Flutterfire CLI to make Firebase to add the Flutter App to my Firebase. Here I installed it using the following command in the powershell of my Flutter app:
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli

This worked and didn't give any issues or warnings. Then came the command to make my Flutter app ready to link it to Firebase:
flutterfire configure --project=PROJECT

Where PROJECT is where I type the real name of my project (so my project is not called PROJECT to make that clear). Here is where I get stuck because I get the following output in my powershell:
Fetching available Firebase projects...
Failed to parse JSON response from Firebase CLI. JSON response: #

     Welcome to...

######## #### ########  ######## ########     ###     ######  ########

##        ##  ##     ## ##       ##     ##  ##   ##  ##       ##

######    ##  ########  ######   ########  #########  ######  ######

##        ##  ##    ##  ##       ##     ## ##     ##       ## ##

##       #### ##     ## ######## ########  ##     ##  ######  ########

# 

Let's make sure your Firebase CLI is ready...

> 

FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
#

This is the point where I am stuck and is my question does anybody know how to fix this?
Some things I have already tried:

Change the name of the Firebase standalone binary to firebase.exe
Reinstalling NodeJs to versions 14.21.3 ,18.5.0, 20.12.2 and 22.0.0 (all 64x)
Adding the path to npm to my system variables as well as personal variables
Doing Firebase init in my project and installing it there. This did install Firebase in my project but didn't make it compatible with Flutter because it did not add the lib/firebase_options.dart file which is neccesary
Double check if I followed all the steps and didn't skip any of them
Running Firebase in the powershell aswell in its own binary


It looks like your FlutterFire CLI is having trouble parsing the output from the Firebase CLI that it calls internally. One thing you can try is to pass in the project ID:  flutterfire configure --project <your project name>.

I have tried that but it didn't seem to work. It still gives the same error.

In the process of doing this I also found this error:
undefined:1


SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\snapshot\firepit\welcome.js:115:27)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:537:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:449:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:537:28)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:747:14)```  
this was when I launched Firebase out of the binary

I found the issue: I was able to install Firebase but it didn't add the path automatically. So I had to find where it was installed and I taught it was in the npm folder but it was inside a folder on that location so I had to make the path to the exact location of where firebase was stored. Also good to note that the binary does not work with flutterfire when wanting to install it

Good to hear your found it, Age. Is there anything that went wrong in the installation (and thus should be a bug), or any documentation or error message that needs updating?

Here's how I add Firebase to the environment and linked it with flutter:

Create a firebase project from firebase console

Followed the instructions in this FlutterFire, so that I can link firebase project with flutter project

After that run the app to make sure that everything is ok.

I need the firebase_CLI to add firebase_options.dart file to the project so I can use DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform in the main.dart

I downloaded CLI from there and installed it (which you can login to your firebase project with your Gmail directly).

I downloaded last version of node.js from there

It suppose to take a while to be installed with powerShell

Make sure that these three paths is added to system variables && personal variables


  C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin
  C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm
  C:\Program Files\nodejs


Run node --version && npm --version to make sure that everything ok

In the command prompt run npm install -g firebase-tools

Then dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli

If the vsCode opened close it and open it again

In the directory of your flutter project in vsCode run flutterfire configure

You can also read these instructions

It suppose to run and everything is ok.



Great solution, only thing I would add is that you should check if in the path variables that you add is where firebase is installed. So just open those folders to see if its actually there and not somewhere else.
